# Were religious people in the 13 colonies more likely to be loyalists?

Tags: american-revolution, protestant-church

I've been teaching 4th/5th graders using the text "Social Studies Alive!" and talking about whether religious people in the colonies tended to lean loyalist vs patriot vs neutral in the years leading up to the American Revolution.  In particular I'm looking at this:

[Page 148](https://archive.org/details/socialstudiesali0000unse_v8d4/page/148/mode/1up?view=theater)

Quoting:

> Other Loyalists were religious leaders who believed that the king's power came from God.  Many of them were members of the Church of England, Great Britain's official church.  They believed that it was wrong to oppose the king.  They told their followers, "You have a duty to be loyal to the church and to the king!"

One of my students had an interesting response:

> A religious person would most likely be a Patriot.  I have learned that many people came to the colonies for religious freedom.

I feel somehow out of my depth.  How to respond to this original thinker in my classroom?

Comment: (Comment from the UK) Yes, many of the original colonists (Puritans) were extreme Protestants who went to America so as to be independent of the Church of England. In England, the Puritans opposed the King in our Civil Wars of the 1640s. But all this was a century before the American Revolution. Presumably by then not all 'religious people' in the colonies were Nonconformists.

Comment: You completely dropped the nuance in what denomination/flavor of very religious the individuals/groups/colonies were. Because that has a massive influence on how they saw Britain.

Comment: I have a vague memory of some comments on another question about how penal colonies (like Georgia and Australia) were oddly more loyal to the crown than other types of colonies. That kind of points to the opposite. :-)

Comment: Appropriate answers for your students will depend a great deal on whether you are teaching in a public school, a private school, or a religious school. Also remember that while Massachusetts was founded by people escaping religious persecution in Europe, nearly all of the other New England colonies were founded by people escaping religious persecution in Massachusetts.

Comment: By "Patriot", do you mean "revolutionary"? This must be a new definition of "patriot" that I'm not aware of....

Comment: @KateBunting I am using _Social Studies Alive!,_ a rather standard sort of textbook, plus _George vs. George: The American Revolution As Seen from Both Sides,_ and a varied collection of other texts that students choose.  Given the above, "religious person" probably means Christian, though we haven't delved into this topic deeply.  Also, back then religion was taken more seriously, from my understanding; so just how religious was a "religious person?" I don't really know.

Comment: @arp public school in San Francisco, California.  I would say the demographic is "not very religious."

Comment: @JamesK Yes, patriot = revolutionary, within our context.  I don't know much about the historic origin of "patriot" in the 13 colonies (or elsewhere), so I've assumed up to now that this definition is sound.  Perhaps I've been wrong?

Comment: @Hobbamok Your point rings true.  But we haven't delved much into the various Christian denominations present in the colonies.  Nor other religions—I don't even know how extensively these were represented at the time.  A comprehensive answer would have to break all of this down.  A simplified answer might just assume a narrower context and disregard the minority religions/denominations.

Comment: @Purplejacket imho no because it still matters and you'd be disregarding critical info. But you can just glance over it with a short sentence like: "some of the denominations were loyal to the Church of England, which tied them directly to the King, while other denominations were actively fleeing from exactly that Church and King, making them far less likely to be royalists

Comment: @arp : reading your comment from Europe, I can't understand how teaching History to children should depend on the type of school they attend. I really hope that historical facts are not distorted by teachers to comply with school direction's agenda ?

Comment: You quoted your student as using the expression 'religious person', not the textbook! It would have been taken for granted that everyone was a Christian, though obviously degrees of commitment varied. That student may not understand that the different denominations of Christianity went hand in hand with different political beliefs.

Comment: @Evargalo tongue in cheek, the wonderful thing about historical facts is that there are *so many different ones* to choose from! More seriously, I hope you don't imagine that there is some magical "unbiased" teaching taking place in 'Europe', because there isn't. Everyone is biased. Even the people that say they aren't.

Comment: @AakashM : Of course there are many bias in Europe too, teaching is fundamentally a subjective activity. I just don't think that the curriculum should *depend a great deal on whether you are teaching in a public school, a private school, or a religious school.* Whether or not religious people were more keen on a given political position in the 18th century should be factually answerable regardless of which children you are talking to.

Comment: I think I might be missing some context you state "talking about whether religious people in the colonies tended to lean loyalist vs patriot vs neutral"... But the quoted book you provide only says that many loyalists were angelicins... Which is really just religious people of a particular denomination. What was the overall context of your classroom discussion?

Comment: @Evargalo I couldn't find any compiled statistics that says one way or another... There might be some. But it is not easily found. There are assumptions that you can make... Quakers, Angelicans, and Puritans can be placed as more likley to be X then Y... just on their religious belief... But I couldn't find any hard evidence to state one way or another.

Comment: One point I haven't seen made here yet, but isn't worth an answer on its own, is that those who came to America for religious reasons vs non-religious ones may not have had the same cultural background (see the religious unrest in German lands, especially). I would expect less loyalty to the British crown from a religious colony originally from Alsace!

Answer (score 20):

What a cool dilemma!!  How fortunate to have a student who engages that deeply. I'm not immediately aware of any statistical summaries of loyalist vs patriot.

(Aside: I'm going to collect some research at the bottom and edit it in as I understand how the evidence supports/undermines the thesis)

(I'm setting aside the controversy over how to define the period "in the years leading up to the American Revolution", and the evolution of the term "Patriot" - since initially all patriots wanted to obey the king, but perceived the context of obedience differently than Parliament did.)

First step would be to distinguish between *religious person*, *adherent of the Church of England*, *dissenter*, *Roman Catholic* and *other *religious person*.  These groups will experience the linkage between crown and faith differently.  The final group would be adherents of African religions, who would have yet another perspective on crown and faith, although in that case I suspect that devotion and discipleship would be a distant second to immediate political needs.

Absent evidence, I see no reason to believe that a religious person who was a  Jew, Muslim, Buddhist, Hindu, etc. would incline either way.

Roman Catholics would  be an interesting case to examine. For Roman Catholics, the linkage between the crown and the faith was decidedly negative, but was probably less significant than the cultural prejudice against their faith. Legal discrimination and persecution by the crown was fixed and effectively passive.  Cultural prejudice was  dynamic and actively threatening (See [Pope night](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Night)).    On the other hand, the contemporary Roman Catholic Church was decidedly, pointedly anti-democratic My hypothesis is Roman Catholics would align with your student's prediction, and skew towards the loyalist cause.  (P. Geerkens makes an excellent point that I must quote)

> Maryland was founded as a Roman Catholic haven - whence the name - yet neither one of the most Loyalist colonies (generally regarded as New York, New Jersey, and the Carolinas) nor one of the most Patriot (Massachusetts, Rhode Island and New Hampshire).

*Aside: [The North American Province of Maryland, a major haven for Roman Catholic settlers, was named in honour of Queen Henrietta Maria. The name was carried over into the current U.S. state of Maryland.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henrietta_Maria_of_France)*

That is pretty strong evidence undermining the student's hypothesis. I'm unlikely to have the time, but it would be interesting to explore P. Geerkens' approach and seek out data on religious distribution in each colony and then graph that against loyalty.  From memory, New England's religious preferences inclined towards dissenters, while the South was largely CoE - although the variations there may be more interesting than the trends.

@RbarryYoung points out that Pennsylvania would be another test case; strong Quaker presence. (although if I recall, the results would be somewhat distorted by the large population of non-English speaking immigrants).

The second step would be to distinguish between adherents of the Church of England and those of [dissenting](https://www.qmul.ac.uk/sed/religionandliterature/dissenting-academies/historical-information/protestant-dissent/) faiths.   Dissenters have no direct linkage between faith and crown. (there may be indirect linkages, but I'll get to that later)  Adherents of the Church of England would experience the greatest direct linkage between crown and faith.  The crown was the head of the church and the head of the church was the crown.  To rebel against one undermined the other.   This topic would quickly get complex; as @justcal reminds us, the [COE in early America](https://nationalhumanitiescenter.org/tserve/eighteen/ekeyinfo/chureng.htm) was complex.

> the Church of England in the colonies suffered from a sluggish rate of growth and a shortage of clergymen throughout much of the seventeenth century. *[National Humanities Center](https://nationalhumanitiescenter.org/tserve/eighteen/ekeyinfo/chureng.htm)*

and

> Like Roman Catholicism, Anglicanism is, historically, a liturgical religious tradition, meaning that great emphasis is placed on observing a formal devotional regimen—the celebration of saints’ days and other holy days, the performance of elaborate, dramatic ceremonies, the conduct of worship by reciting set prayers—all accompanied by sublime organ music and choral singing and led by priests wearing vestments. *IBID*

Perhaps the best *summary* is provided at the end of that article,

> On the other hand, most contemporary scholars would agree that colonial Anglicanism was unwavering in its support of the status quo—the prevailing hierarchies of class, race, and gender that at least some early evangelicals were more inclined to challenge. In short, the current consensus is that Anglicanism was a socially conservative tradition that nonetheless commanded a broad base of support by virtue of its spiritual appeal to the laity. *IBID*

*aside: I think a discussion of liturgical vs cultural vs disciple religious missions is subtle. I doubt that I have the skill to articulate it in a way that is respectful to all concerned. The article that @justcal provided is probably the best short summary directed at students.  A modern treatment is at [Five Marks](https://www.churchofengland.org/sites/default/files/2017-11/mtag-the-5-marks-of-mission.pdf), but I find it plausible that in the pre-Revolutionary period CoE adherence might have affected political behavior less than predicted.  Fascinating topic, but probably beyond the scope of 4th/5th grade students research skills*

[Dissenting faiths](https://www.qmul.ac.uk/sed/religionandliterature/dissenting-academies/historical-information/protestant-dissent/) had already rejected the linkage and accepted that faith was independent of political rule.  Although Quakers again would be a fascinating research project.  I would have predicted Quakers to remain quite neutral, but I recall tales of Quakers who joined the revolutionary cause (although the case that I'm thinking of was under rather extreme provocation;
a British foraging party abused a Quaker family).  I think it would be equally interesting to look at Quakers who chose revolution over faith, and how they related to their faith community after having violated the precepts of pacifism. (I have only a superficial understanding of Quaker pacifism, and am happy to be educated)

***HOWEVER***

The third step - and perhaps the most important - would be to examine the impact of the two beliefs.  Just like today the degree to which the faithful *use* their faith in making political choices can vary, and the degree to which any adherent is attached to a particular dogma can vary.

We can reason (from the existence of Episcopalians post revolution ) that there were devout adherents of the Church of England who were not compelled to flee back to England (or who were prevented by socio-economic factors; the final settlement of loyalist revolutionary war claims didn't occur until after the US civil war.)  It would be an interesting project, probably within the scope of secondary school research, to find an example of a patriot adherent of the Church of England.  I suspect that at this point we'd have to re-approach the issue that I said I'd skip.  The evolution of English colonist to opposition to Parliamentary acts, and eventually to American was subtle and not entirely complete until after the Revolution.

Faith and politics seem to occupy separate dimensions in the soul. I think your student is *probably* correct that they were more closely connected at the time, but the difference was one of degree.

Good luck.

---

## Research

> Religion played a major role in the American Revolution by offering a moral sanction for opposition to the British--an assurance to the average American that revolution was justified in the sight of God. As a recent scholar has observed, "by turning colonial resistance into a righteous cause, and by crying the message to all ranks in all parts of the colonies, ministers did the work of secular radicalism and did it better."  *[LOC](https://www.loc.gov/exhibits/religion/rel03.html)*

Nice quote, but doesn't connect to my hypothesis above. Might be that I'm wrong; might be that we need to dig deeper to find the common threads. The site is full of excellent stuff to explore the student's comment.

> Jonathan Mayhew delivered this sermon--one of the most influential in American history--on the anniversary of the execution of Charles I. In it, he explored the idea that Christians were obliged to suffer under an oppressive ruler, as some Anglicans argued. Mayhew asserted that resistance to a tyrant was a "glorious" Christian duty. In offering moral sanction for political and military resistance, Mayhew anticipated the position that most ministers took during the conflict with Britain. *[LOC](https://Bookmark%20this%20item:%20//www.loc.gov/exhibits/religion/rel03.html#obj083)*

Mayhew was a Congregationalist preacher.  Weak support for my hypothesis.

> The supposed British plot, to impose Anglican bishops in the colonies, aroused atavistic fears that Americans would be persecuted for their religious convictions and further poisoned relations between Britain and the colonies. In this cartoon an indignant New England mob pushes a bishop's boat back towards England, frightening the prelate into praying, "Lord, now lettest thou thy Servant depart in Peace." The mob flings a volume of Calvin's Works at the bishop, while brandishing copies of John Locke and Algernon Sydney on government. The crowd shouts slogans: "Liberty & Freedom of Conscience"; "No Lords Spiritual or Temporal in New England"; and "shall they be obliged to maintain bishops that cannot maintain themselves." *[LOC](https://Bookmark%20this%20item:%20//www.loc.gov/exhibits/religion/rel03.html#obj086)*

Boston's cartoonist urged Boston to reject Bishops.  Rabbit hole: I don't perceive the CoE as Calvinist; not sure why the mob would fling Calvin's works at the Bishop. I interpret the Lords Spiritual and Temporal as a direct reference to the CoE.  I suspect that there is either some subtlety here, or else this is a simple rejection of multiple religious symbols -

Comment: An interesting article [here](https://nationalhumanitiescenter.org/tserve/eighteen/ekeyinfo/chureng.htm) states people generally underestimate the presence of the Anglican Church in the colonies, but overstate the [connection to loyalism](https://nationalhumanitiescenter.org/tserve/eighteen/ekeyinfo/chureng.htm#:~:text=This%20research%20has%20demonstrated%20that%20the%20link%20between%20membership%20in%20the%20Church%20of%20England%20and%20loyalist%20affinities%20was%20tenuous%20at%20best%E2%80%94and%20in%20the%20South%2C%20the%20stronghold%20of%20Anglicanism%2C%20virtually%20non%2Dexistent.).

Comment: Very good catch. Gave you credit in the revisions, but I'm struggling to avoid the fascinating rabbit hole you've presented - the gulf between religious belief and practice - between liturgical participation and disciple's transformation. (I know there is a better word for "execute the disciple's function... what is "Disciple" as a verb. COE seems to contend it is "Transform", but I think that's modern)

Comment: @MCW You wrote: "My hypothesis is that your student is right, that Roman Catholics would skew towards the loyalist cause." — rather, the student wrote "A religious person would most likely be a Patriot"

Comment: Good catch. Revised.

Comment: Maryland was founded as a Roman Catholic haven - whence the name - yet neither one of the most Loyalist colonies (generally regarded as New York, New Jersey, and the Carolinas) nor one of the most Patriot (Massachusetts, Rhode Island and New Hampshire). This in itself would seem to counter the student claim. @Purplejacket

Comment: Growing up in Maryland, we learned in the 3rd grade that it was named after Queen Henrietta Maria, not after a religious icon. (And I was in Catholic school so I'd have expected it be taught otherwise if it were true!)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Maryland wasn't especially Catholic in the mid-18th Century. The dream of a "Roman Catholic Haven" in Maryland was destroyed by 1645.  There was a long period of Puritan control, and the Calverts lost their charter in 1689, regaining it only after Lord Baltimore converted to CofE. The dissolute lifestyle of the Fifth Baron Baltimore,  and the family's struggle for control after he died, made most Marylanders support the revolution.

Comment: I grew up in Pennsylvania and was taught that most of its leaders were Quakers because of William Penn's influence and recruitment of colonists.  Despite that, and despite William Penn himself definitely being vehemently against the declaration by his colony, Pennsylvanians (or their leaders) were seen as being largely in favor of separation from England.  And though very few Quakers participated in the war itself, they generally supported the Declaration and the formation of a new nation.  At least that's what we were taught in school...

Comment: @RBarryYoung It's difficult for pacifists to support armed revolution. Hence the seemingly-equivocal "support (peaceful) separation & new nation, but oppose the declaration of & participation in war".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quakers_in_the_American_Revolution is good, and also illustrates that there was a lot of nuance — not just stark "patriot" / "loyalist" lines.

Comment: @RBarryYoung As William Penn died in 1718, it would be difficult to conclude whether he had any opinion on the Declaration of Independence.  As for his descendants,  they would have had the same reason for opposing Independence as Henry Harford would have.

Comment: @Spencer Hmm, you're right of course, I must have been confusing him with someone else.

Answer (score 12):

There's a really interesting book called "God Against the Revolution: The Loyalist Clergy's Case Against the American Revolution" by Gregg L. Frazer. In it he says:

> Contrary to popular belief and to popular history, there were no particular social, economic, or religious groups that were entirely Whigs or entirely Tories.

> Religious identification played an important role in choosing sides...Interestingly, though the religious lines dividing Whigs and Tories were "quite clearly drawn", they were not drawn with denominational borders. The traditional view is that the Congregationalists and Presbyterians were Whigs and Anglicans (members of the Church of England) were Tories.

> Though religious affiliation clearly played a role, it may not have been the decisive factor for many...Nelson concludes that the key to understanding which side a particular religious group would favor is to look at the "dominant local denomination". Groups that were in "a local minority were everywhere inclined toward Loyalism, while adherents of the dominant local denomination were most often Patriots."...In other words, the traditional view concerning these large denominations is not supported by the facts.

So: no clear answer, but there's a stereotypical answer that's been undermined by historians who think that the strongest correlation between religious affiliation and loyalism is whether or not your religion was in the local minority, suggesting that you might be afraid of what change would mean for your status.

Answer (score 9):

The student makes a good point that having left England to seek religious freedom in the colonies might be expected to incline people away from the Loyalist position.  Likewise, to a lesser extent, coming from a religious and cultural context shaped by other people who had done so.  (After all, by the time of the American Revolution, a large proportion of those resident in the colonies had been born there.)  This should not be ignored.

However, the student seems not to be appreciating the diversity of religious traditions and beliefs in the colonies at the time of the AR.  Not all "religious people" in the colonies moved there to escape religious persecution, or maintained the faith traditions of people who had done.  Presumably, few of the relatively many colonists who belonged to the Church of England were in that category.  Possibly, then, the student could be pushed to express more precisely who they mean by "religious people".

Furthermore, the student may not appreciate that people's positions and decisions are rarely governed by a single consideration alone.  A desire for religious freedom absolutely could be expected to incline people away from favoring a head of state who is also a head of church.  But people may also be influenced by economic concerns (will my business be ruined if the colonies separate from England?), by personal safety concerns (if there is an armed rebellion, might I or members of my family be hurt or killed?), and others.  It might, then, be useful to encourage the student to explore reasons why their "religious people" might nevertheless take the Loyalist position, or it least reject the revolutionary position.

Moreover, it may be that neither you nor the student recognize that *the two positions do not conflict*.  The text claims that **among the Loyalists** were **some** religious leaders who adhered to and taught beliefs revolving around divine appointment of political leadership.  It does not say that *all* religious leaders, even within the CoE, were Loyalists.  It does not speak directly to the positions of religious people in general. One can suppose that Loyalist religious leaders exerted influence over the positions of their laity, but how widespread or effective was that influence?  The premise that the student's "religious people" would skew the other direction is not contradicted by that.  I'm inclined to think that it would be worthwhile to undertake an exercise in critical reading to explore what the passage actually says, and distinguish that from related claims that the passage does not actually make.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't 'everyone know' half the reason the 'Pilgrim Fathers' were so called was that they went to America to escape religious restrictions in England?

Doesn't fleeing religious restriction amount to dissenting from the majority view, at least?

Their fellow colonists were pretty-much by definition, likely to be non-conformists… I stay at home and do everything your way, or I make my own choices.

Is stronger evidence really needed?

Answer (score -2):

[ChristianHeritageFellowship](https://christianheritagefellowship.com/the-pastor-who-fired-the-shot-heard-around-the-world/) describes how pastor Jonas Clark and his parishioners were instrumental in the battle of Lexington.

This and other cases are [documented](https://chuckbaldwinlive.com/Resources/Quotes.aspx#jqa) by [Pastor Chuck Baldwin](https://chuckbaldwinlive.com/Articles/tabid/109/ID/4151/Independence-Now-And-Independence-Forever.aspx).

---

Regarding the comment below: Mr. Baldwin is the pastor of a [highly racially diverse congregation](https://chuckbaldwinlive.com/Articles/tabid/109/ID/3393/Is-Chuck-Baldwin-A-Racist.aspx) who has [extensively](https://chuckbaldwinlive.com/Resources/Quotes.aspx) [preached](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjk9fkf9OuM) and [published](https://chuckbaldwinlive.com/Store.aspx#!/THE-FREEDOM-DOCUMENTS-Expanded-Edition-Book-Compiled-By-Dr-Chuck-Baldwin-SOLD-OUT-Next-printing-scheduled-for-May-16-Pre-Orders-begin-May-1/p/57560546) on faith-based aspects of the American revolution. He takes the side of the Palestinians, as does e.g. [the Israeli historian Ilan Pappe](https://www.palestinechronicle.com/my-israeli-friends-this-is-why-i-support-palestinians-ilan-pappe/). His scripture-oriented views seem to be in conflict with [several parts](https://chuckbaldwinlive.com/Articles/tabid/109/ID/4510/What-Do-Justin-Trudeau-And-Kristi-Noem-Have-In-Common-They-Both-Want-To-Put-You-In-Jail-For-Having-Unpopular-Opinions.aspx) of [the political spectrum](https://chuckbaldwinlive.com/Articles/tabid/109/ID/4342/Only-Donald-Trump-Could-Make-Liberal-Democrats-Sound-Like-Conservative-Constitutionalists.aspx), which might be a parallel to Jonas Clark, and [to someone from 2000 years ago](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2023&version=CEV) .

Comment: For the uninitiated, Mr Baldwin is a far-right politician (not a historian). He also believes that Zionist control the media, mainstream Christianity, and the US government.